# FreeBSD Disable Serial Console from Bootloader?

Tags: freebsd, serial, boot-loader

I have a FreeBSD appliance (meaning I can't open the case or I will void the warranty) that was working well until I accidentally clicked 'Enable Serial Console' and rebooted...

I went to plug in my serial cable and found the device has no serial port.  Consequently the device starts to boot and hangs.

Is there any way to disable the serial console from the FreeBSD bootloader prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console=nullconsole or console=vidconsole